# How to make background image of div go darker on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.google.pt"> 
  <div class="xxxx">
    <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF; padding-top:25%;">Bla bla bla bla</h3>
  </div> 
</a>
```

With this CSS class:

```
.xxxx{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-image:url(images/img.jpg);
  max-width:100%;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
}
```

My question is, what should I do to make the background image of the div go darker when the mouse is over, but just the image, the text stays the same.

Comment: Create a darker version of the image, and add .xxxx:hover to your CSS and set the darker image as the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css **filters**:

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(0.222);
```

More about filters https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-filters.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why only the prefixed version?

Comment: The problem here is the answer contains only safari-chrome solution. And however, filters still haven't wide compatibility, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with another image

```
.xxxx:hover
{
    background-image:url(images/img_darker.jpg);
}
```

where img_darker is darker version of the img you use.

EDİT:

```
a:hover .xxxx{
   background-image:url(images/img_darker.jpg);
}
```

Comment: That didnt work, I'm not sure but maybe its because when i hover on the image is overing on the link that i have before de div, any idea how to solve that?

Comment: It worked, i had a typpo on the code, but is there a way that instead of just go darker make it like fade? Just to stay more beautifull?

Comment: nope.. you cannot achieve it with this. but andrey's answer yes you can

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jm3o7vof/ here's a fiddle for the fade effect with andrey's answer. @Berna

Comment: np! it'd better if you accepted andrey's answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8QMTv/

```
 <button class="btn-img">
        <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/2a/Burj_Al_Arab,_Dubai,_by_Joi_Ito_Dec2007.jpg/220px-Burj_Al_Arab,_Dubai,_by_Joi_Ito_Dec2007.jpg" alt="Dubai" />
        </div>
    </button>
```

```
.btn-img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.btn-img .img-wrap {
    margin: 10px;
}

.btn-img img {
    display: block;
}

.btn-img:hover .img-wrap {
    background-color: black;
}

.btn-img:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation is useful and will be better answer.

Answer (score 1):

you may use :

- linear gradient
- inset shadow
- background-blend-mode
- filter but forget IE at this time

```css
h1 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
}
h1:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
}
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
}
h2:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
h3 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
h3:hover {
  background-blend-mode: color;
}
h4:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
  filter: brightness(80%)
}
```

```html
<h1>title</h1>
<h2>title</h2>
<h3>title</h3>
<h4>title</h4>
```

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bprLjv)

---

you may use gradinets to give some effects hover the background http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/rexVWR add/remove gradients, change colors, change background-size, actually you may lay any pattern over the background-image :)

Comment: this is good too but if the background image has transparent parts it shouldn't do well. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jackjop give a try with the first one, where gradient color is only updated on hover , but, yes, it will fill the entire tag. this was not specified in the question :). Cause in this case, you'll need a pseudo and a filter, but IE will be left aside. if you have a translucide png to share, i' can set a demo too :). i'll be around in a couple (coffee drinking)

Comment: yep, I's just mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before` preselector and filter `brightness`

HTML

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.google.pt"> 
  <div class="xxxx">
    <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF; padding-top:25%;">Bla bla bla bla</h3>
  </div> 
</a>
```

CSS

```
.xxxx{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-width:100%;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  z-index:100;
  position:relative;
}
.xxxx:before{
  position:absolute;
  max-width:100%;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  top:0;
  left:0px;
  content:" ";
  background-image:url(https://images.blogthings.com/thecolorfulpatterntest/pattern-1.png);
  z-index:1;
}
h3{
  z-index:100;
  position:relative;
}
```

.xxxx:hover:before{
   filter: brightness(0.3);
}

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/za7p5cck/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ddj2d0L/)
Does it solve your problem?

you have to put another div (in gray or black) above the picutre, then it seems to get darker while hovering.

```
.yyyy{ 
position:absolute;opacity:0;width: 400px;height: 300px;background-color: #000000;}
.yyyy:hover{
 opacity: 0.3;
}
```